# Too much output leed eclipse die, how to control it

Tags: eclipse, output, nsight

Recently I use nsight to do programming CUDA.
Sometime I print a lot in command line.
Too much output leed eclipse die. But in terminal I just use ctrl+c. In eclipse how to control the output stream. I don't want eclipse stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 Limit output**

You can limit the output console in

```
Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Limit console output
```

[image]

**2 Alternative output stream**

Alternatively you can define another output stream for your run/debug-configuration.

```
Run -> Debug Configurations -> select your configuration -> Tab "Common"
```

[image]